# Parse a URL-String and get the parameters from it

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I got a Problem with parsing a URL-String and get the Parameters from it, with the help of the UrlMatcher class.

Source:

```
<?php 
//RouteCollection
$routes = $this->container->get('routes');
//SubRequest to a Controller (POST)
$response = $this->forward(...);

if($response instanceof RedirectResponse){
    //TargetUrl looks like this 
    //dev.php/admin/twitter-modul/1/show
    //1 is the id of the Entity
    $context = new RequestContext($response->getTargetUrl());
    $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
    //match throws a ResourceNotFoundException
    $parameters = $matcher->match($response->getTargetUrl());
    //Here i need the id paramater from the url
    var_dump($parmeters);
}

return $response;
```

How can I parse a URL-String and get the parameters from it ?

Answer (score -1):

This is not ideal but you could extract the number from the string:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $response->getTargetUrl(), $matches);
$id = implode('', $matches[0]);
var_dump($id);
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for a Symfony 2 way :) But this one could work.

Comment: Ahah I agree 100% but I don't know a symfony way for this :) the only thing I could think of is extracting the id from the string directly. Someone will find a Sf2 way, I am sure.

Comment: hey, thank you for your response. 

1) Didn't saw it thanks, but this is not the problem.  The match method throws a ResourceNotFound exception
which means that the php interpreter does not come so far.
2) This will not work, because the targetUrl have no host in it, so $host would be NULL.
3) Sure this would work, but i want to use the symfony components.